# What is location.search in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to know what `location.search.substring(1)` actually does. I saw this code on some website. I tried to print using `alert`, but this did not give any result. Is it supposed to alert location href?

```
alert(location.search.substring(1))
```

Comment: location.search returns the query portion of a URL including the Question mark (?). 
This return a string

and then we do substring operation on that string. substring(1) means return the string skipping the first character. I our case "the question mark".

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Answer (score 55):

```
http://example.com/index.php?foo=bar

location.search
> ?foo=bar
location.search.substring(1)
> foo=bar
```

So that code will return the entire query parameters *without* the question mark.

Comment: I do not know it is incorrect thats why i posted question here

Comment: @jchand your question isn't incorrect - Tim's answer is what's incorrect. My other comment was in reply to his answer.

Answer (score 21):

The location.search property contains the query string of an URI (including the ?), if any.

Example:

```
http://www.example.org/index.php?param=arg
location.search is ?param=arg
```

So your code snips away the leading ? and returns `param=arg`.

Comment: Your first sentence doesn't match your example - location.search _includes_ the ?.

Answer (score 16):

> The search property returns the query portion of a URL, including the question mark (?).

That means, that `location.search.substring(1)` should return the data *without* the question mark.

```
// http://www.example.com/index.html
console.log(location.search.substring(1)); // no query string, so displays nothing

// http://www.example.com/index.html?property=value
console.log(location.search.substring(1)); // should display "property=value"
```

---

The "query porpotion" is the query string:

```
http://www.example.com/?property=value&property2=value
                       |        query string         |
```

Comment: can you please describe what is query portion on href and how it look like

Answer (score 7):

e.g. if you have the following url

```
http://www.example.org/index.htm?Browser=Netscape
```

then `window.location.search` will return `?Browser=Netscape` as a string

Comment: I am trying to alert it like alert(window.location.search); I am writing some query string in the url and then click to see alert but it doesn't show any thing. The alert pops up but showing nothing. what could be causing that?

Comment: I would need an exact example of your url and query to reproduce your issue. Though u also could try the debug mode of your browser. set a breakpoint at the line you want and just type `window.location.search` or `window.location` in your console. Its a much better approach than alert to see whats goin on.

Answer (score 7):

location.search returns a query string including the initial question mark. The substr method is to remove the initial question mark from the returned query string.

The reason why you're not getting any results in the alert() is because you're trying to read query string on a website which doesn't have any.

Here's how you test:

1. Go to this [URL](https://www.google.com/?name=rehan&age=22&message=nomessageshere!)
2. Open up the console on your browser
3. Paste the code snippet shared below and hit enter

```js
var container = {};
location.search.split('&').toString().substr(1).split(",").forEach(item => {
    container[item.split("=")[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item.split("=")[1]) ?  item.split("=")[1]: "No query strings available" ;
});
console.log(container);
```

Old question but the answer might be helpful for new visitors on this page.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the query string, without the initial question mark. You'll only see a result if there's a query string on the page, e.g. http://www.example.com?parameter=value.

Answer (score 1):

Now is year of 2018, this is how you do it in 2018.

Sample URL:

```
http://localhost:10/mapserver1/viewer/?config=viewer_simple1&url=https://maps2.dcgis.dc.gov/dcgis/rest/services/Zoning/MapServer&zoom=17&lat=38.917292&long=-77.036420
```

My working code to extract each query parameter:

```
        var ___zoom;
        var ___lat;
        var ___long;
        var ___basemap;

        var ___type;
        var ___url;
        var ___title;
        var ___opacity;



        if ( location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i) )
        {
             ___zoom = location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[1];
         }

        if ( location.search.match(/lat=([^&]*)/i) )
        {
           ___lat = location.search.match(/lat=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/long=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___long = location.search.match(/long=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/basemap=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___basemap = location.search.match(/basemap=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/type=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___type = location.search.match(/type=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

       if (location.search.match(/url=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___url = location.search.match(/url=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }


        if (location.search.match(/title=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___title = location.search.match(/title=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }

        if (location.search.match(/opacity=([^&]*)/i))
        {
            ___opacity = location.search.match(/opacity=([^&]*)/i)[1];
        }


        //console.log(location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[0]);   //    'zoom=17'
        //console.log(location.search.match(/zoom=([^&]*)/i)[1]);   //     '17'
        console.log(___zoom); 
        console.log(___lat); 
        console.log(___long); 
        console.log(___basemap); 

        console.log(___type); 
        console.log(___url); 
        console.log(___title); 
        console.log(___opacity);
```